# System.xml.dll in APK with while not using System.xml.dll

Tags: unity-game-engine

When i compile my game to android (APK) i see that a system class name, `system.xml.dll`  (almost 2mb) while i do not use system.xml.dll in my project.
Is there a way to detect where it comes from, or is it from one of the plugins?

I do use Firebase, Admob and Json .Net for Unity.

In another project of mine that doesn't have these three plugins, I do **not** have system.xml.dll in the apk build.

Using unity 2018.2.18

Comment: it comes from `System.Xml.Serialization;` do you use this somewhere? and well XML is a quite common format .. possible that one of those plugins use it

Comment: From Nettonsoft (Json .Net), in it's settings XML, it seems to be using `System.Xml.XmlNode`

Comment: yes it seams to come from [SerializeXmlNode](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeXmlNode.htm)